# Построить диаграмму, игнорируя переходы в нуль (Google Chart API)

Tags: php, google-chart, диаграммы

Использую Google Chart API. Вот код примера:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');
  data.addRow(["A", 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["B", 2, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["C", 4, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["D", 0, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["E", 7, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["F", 0, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["G", 8, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["H", 4, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["I", 2, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["J", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["K", 3, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["L", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["M", 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["N", 1, 0.5, 1]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
    hAxis: {title: "Month"},
    series: {1: {type: "line"}}
  });
}
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы линия непрерывно соединяла соседние значения, игнорируя переходы в значения 0.

В моём примере линия строится по точкам 1→2→4→0→7, а нужно, чтобы она соединяла 4 и 7, а не 4 и 0, и только потом уже 0 и 7.

И ещё необходимо, чтобы при выставлении верхнего предела, максимальное значение было именно равно этому пределу. Но выставляю `minValue = 8`, и при достижении максимального значения на оси отрисовывается `minValue + 1` — а мне надо строго то, что я задал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовал через апроксимацию, попробовал реализовать алгоритм, написал. но это просто жесть какая то. Алгорим должен найти кол-во 0 после левого крайнего значения!=0, найти значение правого значения после списка всех 0. Поделить (правое значение после 0 - левое крайнее до 0)/(кол-во 0й), это будет шаг с которым будем увеличивать левое крайнее значение до равенства с правым значением. У меня это все нужно для отрисовки статистики посещаемости за год и даты именно с какой то допустим 01-09-2011 до 20-06-2012, тут явно что может быть огромное кол-во нулей и соедовательно алгорит вешается :)

Да, предметов может быть штук 10. Сделал хоть мение красивую, но зато работающую пилообразную кривую